# Form Validation in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, formvalidation-plugin

so it's not kind of a problem, but when I'm trying to validate my form I usually use a large amount of

```
if(){
}else if(){
}
.
.
.
else{
}
```

but it's both time-consuming and in the means of clean code, it doesn't really appear good.
So is there kind of a Form validation component or a better way to do this?
any reference would be super useful.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation) with  `Yup`

[validation schema](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation)

```
 const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
   firstName: Yup.string()
     .min(2, 'Too Short!')
     .max(50, 'Too Long!')
     .required('Required'),
   lastName: Yup.string()
     .min(2, 'Too Short!')
     .max(50, 'Too Long!')
     .required('Required'),
   email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email').required('Required'),
 });
```

nice get started [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/handling-react-forms-and-validation-with-formik-and-yup-dc789fd9e485)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you prefer to use a package like formik, You can use the answer given by @Yoel.
2. You have Default HTML5 validation that you can use and set validation messages using JS `setCustomValidity()` API.

Comment: Can I suggest you add this link to make your answer more helpful? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Yes, MDN is one of the best.